# Реализация json rpc client через tcp

Tags: json, json-rpc

Есть `json rpc server`, мне с него по запросу надо получать `json` массив, надо, чтобы он выводился в веб-странице.
Хотелось бы реализацию на `php`, но из всего, что у меня получилось это реализация на `nodejs` через `json-rpc-client`, но это нод и он слишком трудоемкий для этой задачи.
Как можно реализовать клиент?

Answer (score 0):

Реализовал через обычный `soket` через `stream_socket_client`

```
$connect = stream_socket_client("tcp://localhost:8080", $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$connect) 
{
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} 
else 
{
    fwrite($connect, 'params');
    while (!feof($connect)) 
    {
        echo fgets($connect);
    }
    fclose($connect);
}
```